# C++ - binding function

Tags: c++, pointers, function, boost, boost-bind

I have some *(library API, so I can't change the function prototype)* function which is written the following way:

```
void FreeContext(Context c);
```

Now, at some moment of my execution I have `Context* local_context;` variable and this is also *not a subject to change.*

I wish to use `boost::bind` with `FreeContext` function, but I need to retrieve `Context` from local variable `Context*`.

If I write my code the following way, the compiler says it's "illegal indirection":

```
boost::bind(::FreeContext, *_1);
```

---

I managed to solve this problem the following way:

```
template <typename T> T retranslate_parameter(T* t) {
   return *t;
}

boost::bind(::FreeContext,
            boost::bind(retranslate_parameter<Context>, _1));
```

But this solution doesn't seem really good to me. Any ideas on how to solve this using something like `*_1`. *Maybe writing a small lambda function?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Boost.Lambda which have overloaded the `*` operator for `_n`.

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

typedef int Context;

void FreeContext(Context c) {
    printf("%d\n", c);
}

int main() {
    using boost::lambda::bind;
    using boost::lambda::_1;

    Context x = 5;
    Context y = 6;
    Context* p[] = {&x, &y};

    std::for_each(p, p+2, bind(FreeContext, *_1));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use either Boost.Lambda or Boost.Phoenix to have a working `operator*` on a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

You can also place the `Context` pointer in a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter:

```
#include <memory> // shared_ptr

typedef int Context;

void FreeContext(Context c)
{
   printf("%d\n", c);
}

int main()
{
   Context x = 5;
   Context* local_context = &x;

   std::shared_ptr<Context> context(local_context,
                                    [](Context* c) { FreeContext(*c); });
}
```

Not sure this is relevant though. Good luck!

Comment: Lambda expression is supported only in C++0x.